# How to share configuration.properties file across multiple independent maven projects?

Tags: java, maven

I have multiple maven projects.
One of this is the core project which contains many classes used by other projects.

```
- Core project
  - config.properties file
  - SingletonClass
- Project A
  - ClassXX
- Project B
  - ClassYY
```

I have a properties.config file inside my core project.
In this core project I have a Singleton class which is used to load the properties.config file elements.

Singleton class of core project loads properties file using the following relative path:

```
"/config.properties"
```

This means that it will search this file inside the current working dir.
This also mean that if I use the singleton class, the current working dir will be different.
For example, if project A uses my singleton class to load a config value, it will try to find config.properties file inside its root folder and so it will not be able to find it, becouse the real path is different (root folder of core project).

So my question is:

Is there any way to share a config.properties file across multiple maven projects?

EDIT:
thanks to davidxxx,
the best way was to use

```
InputStream is = MySingleton.class.getResourceAsStream("/conf/singleton.properties");
```

To let it works i have also create a resource folder(conf) and set it in build path.
I also have had to specify what to package in my core project pom.xml as follow:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/conf</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: I think the issue you have is to load a property file via file access instead of classpath access which means using `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/config.properties")` which will work also in a jar file...and solve the whole issue. The other question why do you need a property file? I would always ask myself if this is really needed?

Comment: I have already tried this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/config.properties");
In this way this.getClass().getResourceAsStream whill search "config.properties" file inside the root folder of current project (not the singletone class, but the project in which singletone.getInstance() is called) and so it will not find the file

Comment: It will search in the jar file if you use this jar which contains your singleton in other projects as dependencies...otherwise you are doing something wrong. Best would be to make a test project with the same structure like yours and put that on github etc. so we can take a look ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This mean that it will search this file inside the current working
>   dir. This also mean that if i use the singleton class, the current
>   working dir will be different.

The problem is the way you are using to retrieve the properties file.
If  your singleton needs to be exported as a dependency in a JAR, you have not to use the current working directory to load the properties file.
The properties file should be in the classpath and the singleton class could use its classloader to get the resource.

For example suppose the properties is located in the conf folder that is added to the runtime classpath, in your singleton class you could write something like that to load the resources :

```
InputStream is = MySingleton.class.getResourceAsStream("/conf/singleton.properties");
```

With this way of doing, this will work in both cases.

Comment: I have already tried this way, but i put the conf file in the root folder. it should have worked too, shouldn't it?
I have tried the following line "MySingleton.class.getResourceAsStream("/singleton.properties"); and it doesn't work. What i have to change in my code? Should i create a folder conf and set it as resource folder in my core project? and why it doesn't work with root folder?

Comment: As you use Maven, you can place the properties file in the `src/main/resources ` folder of the project that hosts it. In this way, `MySingleton.class.getResourceAsStream("/singleton.propertie‌​s");` should  work everywhere.

Comment: Yes i know, in this way it works fine, but what i was trying to do is to maintain only one single property file, the one in the core project. If i place many copies of my prop file, every time i have to change something, i have to change it in every project.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the Properties Maven plugin [here](http://This%20site%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20reached%20%20mojo.codehaus.org%20took%20too%20long%20to%20respond.%20Go%20to%20http://codehaus.org/%20Search%20Google%20for%20mojo%20codehaus%20org%20properties%20maven%20plugin%20ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT). This will let you define your properties in an external file, and the plugin will read this file.

With this configuration :

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <files>
                        <file>my-file.properties</file>
                    </files>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

and if you have, in your properties file the following lines:

```
spring-version=1.0
mysql-version=4.0.0
```

then it's the same thing as if you wrote, in your pom.xml, the following lines:

```
<properties>
  <spring-version>1.0</spring-version>
  <mysql-version>4.0.0</mysql-version>
</properties>
```

Using this plugin, you will have several benefits:

1. Set easily a long list of properties
2. Modify the values of these properties without modifying the parent pom.xml.

Comment: What i want to do is to use the values of my conf file inside the java code, not in the pom.xml. Is this plug-in able to allow me to get the content of my vars from a java class? For example, can i load vars stored in config.properties file from Project A ClassXX ?

Comment: That is the wrong way. Apart if you suggest solutions you should use the most recent versions of the plugins. http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/